# How to Parse and Create Multi-Field Xml

Tags: javascript, java, oracle

I want to save an xml with more than 450 elements to oracle database. Normally I create a column in a table for each element and save it there. Of course, I create separate tables for repetitive fields in XML and link these tables together. I'm using Java to do this. Now that the number of fields is too many, I couldn't decide how to save my XML java model to the database. Another point of the job is to show the saved fields to the user via a react screen. Another problem for me is doing the opposite of this process. In other words, requesting 450 field entries from a react screen, saving them to the database and creating and sending XML with java. I am very undecided on the subject, I need your comments.

Example data ile like below;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns15:sendRequest xmlns:ns4="http://xxx.yyyy.zzz/schemas/Pay/" xmlns:ns15="http://xxx.yyyy.zzz/services/Send/">
    <ns4:Mes SN="12122">
        <ns4:Trh>12/05/2020</ns4:Trh>
        <ns4:GonKK>9999</ns4:GonKK>
        <ns4:GonSK>90001</ns4:GonSK>
        <ns4:AlKK>8888</ns4:AlKK>
        <ns4:AlSK>99999</ns4:AlSK>
        <ns4:Onc>2</ns4:Onc>
        <ns4:IslTur>K14</ns4:IslTur>
        <ns4:Ttr>1000,00</ns4:Ttr>
        <ns4:OdmTur>03</ns4:OdmTur>
        <ns4:IslKynk>0</ns4:IslKynk>
        <ns4:Ynlndrc>XXXXXXx</ns4:Ynlndrc>
        <ns4:YnlndrcHesN>12121212121</ns4:YnlndrcHesN>
        <ns4:YnlndrcKimN>121212122</ns4:YnlndrcKimN>
        <ns4:SWMesGonD>H</ns4:SWMesGonD>
        <ns4:MST>
            <ns4:NhAlKrm>XXXXXXXXX</ns4:NhAlKrm>
            <ns4:AmrBlgKodS>
                <ns4:Amr>XXXXXXXX</ns4:Amr>
            </ns4:AmrBlgKodS>
            <ns4:NhAlBlgKodS>
                <ns4:NhAl>XXXXXXXXX</ns4:NhAl>
                <ns4:NhAlHesN>121212122</ns4:NhAlHesN>
            </ns4:NhAlBlgKodS>
        </ns4:MST>
    </ns4:Mes>
</ns15:SendRequest>
```

Comment: Can you share an example XML that you are parsing the values from? Is there a specific reason that you can not just pass the whole XML to the oracle and parse it from there to store the data into the tables? It would also be helpful if you could share some example tables/columns that the XML data is being saved in.

Comment: We don't have sample xml available because we haven't started yet. We only have xsd files. But basically there are complex types and sequences nested inside each other. And they contain a total of more than 450 elements. Normally we do the parse process in java. How is the parse in the oracle you mentioned? When we want to create and send an xml ourselves, do we need to create it in oracle again?

Comment: if you can mock up an example XML of something you might receive, I can show an example of how it would be done. Even an abridged version that only has 10-20 fields.

Comment: I add an example data. Thank you.